# Call MVC Html helper extension in ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on the MVC project in which one of the aspx page also exists for SSRS reports. Here, I have a HTML helper written for returning some multi-lingual text value. So, For all the report labels, I need to call HTML helper extension to get the string text. Is there any way that I can call that method from my aspx page??

Note: I cannot do this from Code behind since all the labels exists in aspx that I do not want to migrate it to code behind.

**So far I tried**

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Vibrant.HtmlHelperExtension" %>
<asp:Label Text="<%# ReturnKeyValue("Brief") %>" meta:resourcekey="lblBrief" ID="lblBrief" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
```

The above one is not able to call the method and I am getting `The name 'ReturnKeyValue' does not exist in the current context` exception.

Comment: Is `ReturnKeyValue` a public static method? The normal scope rules still apply.

Comment: Yes. It is a public static method.

Comment: Although your view has the correct Namespace imported, perhaps the internal context that evaluates the Text attribute does not. Does it work if you change the Text value to "<%# Vibrant.HtmlHelperExtension.ReturnKeyValue("Brief") %>"?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found. Maybe you can try.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

> HTML Helper is rendered with <%= %> tags instead of <% %> tags. If you
>   don't include the equal sign, then nothing gets rendered to the
>   browser.